# `doctype` vs `charset` in HTML 5

Tags: html, character-encoding, doctype

**I am curious about the relationship between `DOCTYPE` and `charset` in an HTML 5 file.**

Using the default HTML template in VSCode produces the following markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**My question is, do we need both `DOCTYPE` and `charset`?**

If the `doctype` is set to `html` (which refers to HTML 5), and we know that `utf-8` is the default `charset` for HTML 5, do we have to specify the `charset` using the `meta` tag or does the browser know?

Answer (score 3):

> My question is, do we need both DOCTYPE and charset?

Yes

> If the doctype is set to html (which refers to HTML 5), and we know that utf-8 is the default charset for that doctype

It isn't. Browsers perform [complex sniffing](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#determining-the-character-encoding) to determine the character encoding. Specifying it explicitly is more reliable.

Comment: I may have confused "default" with "preferred" charset.

Answer (score -2):

The `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration is used to inform a website visitor's browser that the document being rendered is an HTML document.
`<!DOCTYPE html>` is doctype of html 5.

`@charset` specifies the character encoding used in the style sheet, and `<meta charset="utf-8" />` specifies the encoding for the HTML document

Comment: "the document being rendered is an HTML document." — No, you're thinking of the `Content-Type` HTTP header. The Doctype tells the browser to render in Standards mode.

Comment: "charset specifies the character encoding used in the style sheet" — No. It specifies the encoding for the HTML document.

Comment: `@charset` specifies the character encoding used in the style sheet, and  `<meta charset="utf-8" />` specifies the encoding for the HTML document

Comment: Yes, but nobody mentioned CSS or `@charset` until your comment just now.

Comment: I have Edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score -2):

It is a good rule to prepare your website for most browsers and platforms.
The use of both will garantee that most technologies can read all they need to represente your site.

So yes... rule of thumb.... always add default preferences in your code, just in case.

Best regards.